# Как правильно реализовать на C++ padding method 2? (ISO/IEC 9797-1)

Tags: c++, файлы, шифрование, aes

У меня есть некоторый файл. В цикле записываю из него 128 битный блок, в массив 4*32 бита (допустим, для последующего AES шифрования).

Необходимо реализовать метод дополнения 2 (единичный бит + нули до конца блока). Я написал такой код (разумеется, внутри цикла по ходу чтения файла):

```
std::array<int32_t, 4> block;
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&block), sizeof block);

    if (static_cast<unsigned long>(input.gcount()) < sizeof block) {
        int16_t *tmp = reinterpret_cast<int16_t *>(block.begin());
        tmp[input.gcount() - 1] = 0x1000;
        for (auto i = input.gcount(); i < 16; ++i) {
            tmp[i] = 0x0000;
        }
    }
```

Но получается некорректно - обрезается лишнее либо в блок вообще попадают данные из предыдущего блока. Что я сделал не так? Может быть есть более изящный метод?

Comment: Цикл обнуления большой получается. До 16 итераций по `int16_t` при размере блока 128 бит. Т.е. выход за границы, а значит UB. Ну и `std::array` тут как-то не к месту. Плюс, что будет если `gcount` вернет 0? Ещё один выход за границы.

Comment: @alexolut, чем `std::array` не угодил?

Comment: @ixSci хотя бы тем, что тип итератора кастуется к указателю. Хотя итератор implementation defined.

Comment: @alexolut, значит нужно `begin` заменить на `[0]`, но это не повод отказываться от `std::array`.

Comment: @ixSci ну, может быть. Надо дальше смотреть как он там используется. Лично я бы объявил обычный массив, ибо так короче. Да и вот еще, что меня смутило так это мешанина стилей си и плюсов. Если уж юзать std::array, то и размер надо через член size получать, а не sizeof.

Comment: @alexolut, безусловно, Ваши замечания обоснованы и код должен быть изменён так, чтобы полноценно использовать возможности `std::array`. А вот пассаж касательно «обычного массива» выдаёт в Вас латентного сишника. Нельзя таким быть :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = input.gcount();
if (n < 16)
{
    block[n++] = 0x80;
    for (int i = n; i < 16; i++)
        block[i] = 0;
}
```

Здесь бит - 0x80, и блок типа байт (uint8_t)